# Determining plot binwidths matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

So my question is a little open-ended. What I really want is some insight on how people determine their bin widths when setting up plots using matplotlib/seaborn.

I get that setting an equally distributed histogram goes kinda like this:

```
plt.hist(data, bins=range(min(data), max(data) + binwidth, binwidth))
```

However, I am struggling with quickly coming up with the visually pleasing binwidths on datasets and I spend A LOT of time just guessing.

What do you do? Do you look at dataframe.describe() and do some quick mental math? Or something else?

Comment: In the documentation of [numpy.histogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) there is an explanation of many methods to determine the number of bins. Which once the minimum and maximum are fixed determines the bin width.

Comment: That definitely helped put me in the right direction. I was able to calculate some bin widths, but I feel like my goal of understanding is now becoming esoteric to the problemset. Thank you! You helped a lot.